# Bing map with search control and current location using openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Can We use bing map with search control (search location - like London) and current location using openlayers. openlayer we are using for adding markers.

Comment: See [v2.2.0](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder/releases/tag/2.2.0) release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension for Openlayers 3 called Geocoder thanks to Jonatas Walker who developped it, here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HichamZouarhi/eLgdfhk8/) made by him, ( I just forked it ) you can base your search by osm, photon or if you have a key to google geocode api.

```
//Instantiate with some options and add the Control
  var geocoder = new Geocoder('nominatim', {
    provider: 'osm',
    lang: 'en',
    placeholder: 'Search for ...',
    limit: 5,
    keepOpen: true
  });
  map.addControl(geocoder);
```

Now for the current location you can use the geolocation [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html) it allows you to get your position based on network location or if you are using it in mobile with cordova you can get the precise network+gps location

Comment: Thanks Hicham Zouarhi

Comment: As of [v2.2.0](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder/releases/tag/2.2.0), Bing API is supported.